# How to create data flow diagrams using Java

Tags: java, parsing, graph, dataflow

I'm an engineering student; I studied dataflow graphs. I already made parser using Antlr,
but I don't know how to make dataflow diagrams. I read some paper that one can make dataflow graphs using Java. Please help me.

Comment: What is it you really want to do?  What are you parsing (Java source code, or code for something else [what?]).   Are you trying to produce dataflow graphs for Java, or dataflow graphs for the something else?  Can you provide an example of input and output?

Comment: If your problem is producing a data flow graph from a parsed procedural language, a parser isn't enough; you need other analysis machinery. See semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html. The question is where do you get all the stuff-beyond-parsing that you need to do this?  If what you are parsing represents the dataflow graph directly, then its merely a matter of building nodes and linking them together with dataflow arcs.

Answer (score 1):

[`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/) may be used for this, as discussed in [review article](http://www.gridnexus.org/_files/Hudson-Biosilico-2-4-Final.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans Visual Library can be used for this:

http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/

You don't need to build a NetBeans platform application (or even use NetBeans) in order to use it: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-create-visual-applications